# Помогите с fosuserbundle symfony2

Tags: symfony2

Я новичек в symfony2, пытаюсь разобраться в чужом коде. Насколько я понял, там используется ***fosuserbundle*** для доступа к страницам, но я не могу понять как он работает. Помогите понять, куда смотреть.

Кстати, при переходе на главную, если не залогиненый, перекидывает на /login. Как это убрать? Спасибо

Comment: ссылка на security.xml - https://yadi.sk/d/BWhHtpDdudZ62

Comment: я так понял, вы просто разбираетесь с чужим проектом. Если так - временно закомментируйте 70 строку в файле security.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток. 
Настройка FOSUserBundle достаточно проста.

Лучше всего разбираться по официальной [документации к бандлу](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html).

Для того, чтобы редирект с главной не перекидывал на логин нужно изменить настройки безопасности в файле `app/config/security.yml`.
После прочтения документации все должно быть достаточно прозрачно. Если возникли трудности - добавьте текущий `app/config/security.yml` к вашему вопросу.

Comment: добавил ссылку в вопрос

Comment: @Diefair, на 70 стоке security.yml у вас стоит ограничение по регулярному выражению - ```- { path: ^/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN ,ROLE_SPORTSMEN,ROLE_TRAINER,ROLE_ZAV,ROLE_METODIST,ROLE_OPEKUN]}```.  Что у вас находится на главной? Все зависит от того, можно ли показывать контент главной всем пользователям. Плюс вопрос еще по иерархии ролей. В ```access_control``` прописаны роли, которых нет в ```role_hierarchy```.